# How can I start Emacs with predefined window?

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to make my Emacs start with predefined frame as my attached screenshot?
I am not familiar enough how to do it in my .emacs script...

[image: Emacs with three frame]

It is as simple as doing :

1. split-window-horizontally (create two window side by side)
2. split-window-vertically (split the first window in the left into two part).

And in the last window, I want it to upload a calendar.
I make this arrangement mostly because my monitor have a broken LCD in the left part of it. So my code must be in the right side of the screen :)

**EDIT 1**
Based on Juanleon answer, I add another eshell window + open a specific *.org file (which is my assumption should I start emacs for project work) :

```
;my preferred working space                                                                                                                                                                                                       
(find-file "docs/steps.org")
(split-window-horizontally)
(other-window 1)
(calendar)
(other-window 2) ;main code                                                                                                                                                                                                       
(split-window-vertically)
(other-window 1)
(eshell)
(other-window 2)
```

Resulting this visual :
[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el. Seems to be a general solution.

Comment: Registers can be used to save window configuration. And they'll remember it no matter how complex. If think this configuration will never change, @juanleon's answer is simpler and skills be enough.

Comment: Hi @abo-abo : thanks for the link, I've read it sometime about that, but I think it's too complicated. :)

Comment: You're right @BruceConnor, I use (if I am not mistaken) winner mode for an easy way of reverting to previous window configuration. But currently I am satisfied with my window arrangement. Hence, Juanleon solution is just what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put that at the end of your init file:

```
    (split-window-horizontally)
    (other-window 1)
    (calendar)
    (other-window 1)
```

Comment: Great! Just what I want it : nothin more, nothing less. Stackoverflow community never disappointed me with any Emacs question ;)